# How to load test on an API level?

Tags: performance-testing, web-api-testing

I like to simulate test-clients on an API level (so I  like to skip the UI) that act as if e.g. 1000 clients execute tasks at the same time to see how the server stands. 
So basically I am looking for a tool which helps me to define / scripts to run many API calls at the same time - does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on SO. You might want to try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (but check for how to ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1000 clients I'd prefer [Gatling](http://gatling.io), it can create higher loads with less resources, though it's limited to http request only and you need to develop the scenario in Scala (don't be afraid, there is a recorder that'll help you a lot). Further the reports are nicers.

Apart from that, [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - as mentioned by mm759 - will work as well. It's UI is bit more intuitive. Though for 1000 users you might require distributed load generators.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It can be used to generate load and measure the performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try Microsoft Webtest.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818498.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[LoadUI](https://www.loadui.org/) is a pretty good tool, specifically for load testing API's.

If your familiar with API testing, you might have used SoapUI before, so LoadUI is from the same people, but load testing the API.

[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is another good one.

Try invest a little time for a Proof of Concept with these and see what fits your needs best.